# I need help setting up these limits of integration (triple integrals)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the volume of the solid bound on top by $z=7$, bottom by $z=7x^2+7y^2$, integrating over $z$. I've looked in three different textbooks and still don't understand, asked my professor and they won't write back. So I have drawn a picture, and I have the following (the red limits are wrong):
\begin{align}
\int_{\color{red}{1/\sqrt{2}}}^{\color{red}{-1/\sqrt{2}}}\int_{\color{red}{-\sqrt{1/\sqrt{2}-x^2}}}^{\color{red}{\sqrt{1/\sqrt{2}-x^2}}}\int_{7x^2+7y^2}^7z\:dz\:dy\:dx.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Could anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: sorrry, the red limits are your solution?

Comment: @Essam Yes, that is what I have worked out, and it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the bottom line is given by $7x^2+7y^2 = 7(x^2+y^2)$. Therefore we are looking for those values of $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+y^2\le 1$, which as you might know is the circle around the origin in the $xy$-plane with radius 1. Because we are dealing with a circle it is advisable to use polar coordinates. That is we have,
\begin{equation}
7\int_{x,y\,\,:\,\, x^2+y^2\le 1}1-(x^2+y^2)dA = 7\int_{r,\theta\,\,:\,\,r\le 1\,\,\&\,\,0\le\theta\le2\pi} (1-r^2)rdA = 14\pi\int_{0}^{1}r-r^3dr.
\end{equation}

---

The above is merely a hint for a 'cleaner' solution. It is also doable directly though. In that case we need $-1\le x\le 1$ and then $-\sqrt{1-x^2}\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}$ giving the inegral
\begin{equation}
7\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}1-(x^2+y^2)dydx
\end{equation}

Comment: The OP didn't ask for the value of the integral or for its computation in cylindrical coordinates, but only for establishing the integration bounds.

Comment: Ahh I see my mistake. It is of radius $1$, not of radius $1/\sqrt{2}$...I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: good luck with your future exercises;)

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{7x^2+7y^2}^{7}zdzdydx$$